# DocuSign - Embedded Signing in a native application

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to know if it is possible to use signatures embedded in a native Windows-based application to make face-to-face signing possible.

I have seen that it is possible to use this for a web application but is it possible for an application running under Windows?

If so, what APIs should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using a web view component. The signing ceremony itself is hosted by DocuSign and displayed using a browser-like window in your app. For Windows, [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2) or similar.

APIs will be the same as for any other DocuSign embedded signing application:

1. Authentication to obtain an access token. Probably implicit grant or perhaps a different grant if used in conjunction with a secure server component.
2. Send the envelope using Envelopes:create
3. Obtain a URL for the signing ceremony via EnvelopeViews:recipientView.

See the [curl example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl), workflow 1.